# Downloading datapoints by Dimension from Amazon CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am publishing a custom metric into CloudWatch with two dimensions:

```
aws cloudwatch --region ap-southeast-1 put-metric-data --namespace CustomNS --metric-name ApiReqCount --dimensions ApiName=TestAPI,ApplicationName=App1 --timestamp 2017-03-07T05:00:00.000Z --statistic-value Sum=7,Minimum=1,Maximum=7,SampleCount=1
```

If I query with all of the dimensions, it gives the datapoints:

```
aws cloudwatch --region ap-southeast-1 get-metric-statistics --namespace CustomNS --metric-name ApiReqCount --dimensions Name=ApiName,Value=TestAPI Name=ApplicationName,Value=App1 --statistics Sum --start-time 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z --end-time 2017-03-08T12:00:00Z --period 300
```

However when I query, and no dimensions or partial dimensions are specified, I do not get back datapoints:

```
aws cloudwatch --region ap-southeast-1 get-metric-statistics --namespace CustomNS --metric-name ApiReqCount --dimensions Name=ApiName,Value=TestAPI --statistics Sum --start-time 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z --end-time 2017-03-08T12:00:00Z --period 300
```

What I really want is that I need all datapoints returned when no dimensions are specified, I'd like to optionally filter these datapoints via Dimensions.

Comment: Also, please note that you never get back the original datapoints. You only receive calculated values, such as Average, Count, Min or Max for a given time period.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query for partial dimension or mix dimensions even if they are identical.

From the documentation:

> CloudWatch treats each unique combination of dimensions as a separate metric, even if the metrics have the same metric name. You can't retrieve statistics using combinations of dimensions that you did not specifically publish.

See examples on: [Amazon CloudWatch Concepts - Dimensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Dimension)